# Arrow Animation on Listview item

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I would like to `animate` an arrow towards the direction to some point on a `ListView`. Similar to what you see in a GPS (where the arrow moves as the vehicle changes heading).

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;


    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new DataHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.locationName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.locationName);
        holder.locationElevation = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.locationElevation);
        heading = getHeading(); 

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (MountainHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Loc loc = data[position];
    holder.locationName.setText(loc.locationName);
    holder.locationElevation.setText(loc.locationElevation);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(loc.icon);

    return row;
}
```

Originally I added an animation to `holder.image` but that animates all of them (not individually). PS, the image is an arrow. I have the heading values I just need to know how to animate these arrows based on that info. Any ideas?